# Change the delay before a key is repeatedly sent after depressing it

Tags: linux, keyboard, fedora, i3-window-manager

When I press down a key on my keyboard, after a brief delay the key-code is repeatedly sent if I continue to hold the key. How can I manipulate this delay on my linux machine?

I work in terminals a lot scrolling through long manuals using vi-like keys and I would like to begin to scroll immediately after I depress the `j` or `k` key instead of having to wait for a second or so. Is this possible?

Also, at which level in the system is this feature implemented? Is that controlled at hardware level or the OS? Or is it even application-specific?
And while we're at it: is there a proper name for this delay?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the question has been asked numerous times with different wording, e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58651/adjusting-keyboard-sensitivity-in-a-command-line-terminal). The settings I'm looking for are referred to as *keyboard sensitivity*.

The command that did it for me is `xset`.

```
# Set the keyboard repeat delay to 200 ms
sudo xset r rate 200
```

Another command, `kbdrate`, did not work for my setup.

Answer (score 0):

On my KDE, this is part of the user customization (Hardware>Input devices>Keyboard):

[image]

Comment: I'm using i3wm on fedora30. Is there any shell command which achieves the same?

Comment: I don't use these, but I suggest to add this information in the question (and maybe even in the title) and add relevant tags (i3wm being possbily the most important).